# Mark Gmail emails as "followup"

Tags: gmail, tasks

Is there some way (Chrome plugin?) that allows one to mark Gmail emails as "followup needed on date such and such"? I love this functionality in Outlook, and always miss it when using Gmail. This should be integrated with some tasks application (Remember the Milk, perhaps).

This is my main handicap when working on Gmail instead of Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now just using FollowUpThen.com, it's the simplest and most reliable solution (and it's free).

Just email whatever you want to an address such as 2hours@followupthen.com or 5days@followupthen.com, archive the email, and you'll get it again at the requested time.

Boomerang is also an option, but it was a bit buggy for me so I switched back to FUT.

Comment: See also sanebox.com for a similar but slightly better solution.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the Task Functionality.  When clicking an email, you can click more actions and then click "Add to Tasks".

With tasks, you can set reminders, due dates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have two options.

1. You can either use your Stars to indicate follow-up needed. However, you can't specify a certain date for that followup.
2. You can go to "More actions" > "Add to tasks". From the Task menu, you can specify a due date.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Boomerang for GMail](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/index.html) to do just this. This Chrome Extension can put an email back into your inbox on a date selected by you.

Answer (score 1):

The new [Google Inbox](http://inbox.google.com) seems to do what you want. It lets you snooze a message to a specific time.

While the message is snoozed, it does not show up in your inbox.

[image: The Snooze until menu in Google Inbox]

Answer (score 0):

Install [any.do](http://any.do) for chrome. Sync [any.do](http://any.do) with your Google account and double check your Gmail. I just had to disable one add-on at labs (the preview panel) and everything is working perfect! Give it a try!

See following article: [Any.DO’s Chrome app now lets you create to-do lists directly from Gmail](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2012/10/31/any-do-updates-its-chrome-extension-to-let-you-create-to-do-lists-directly-from-gmail/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ActiveInbox, which does exactly what you are asking, within GMail itself: http://www.activeinboxhq.com/